# IF Statements with 3 options

Tags: google-sheets

I have 3 possible evaluation values in my spreadsheet (I have to use the values with digits and words):

- 1.0 - Doesn't meet expectations
- 2.0 - Meets expectations
- 3.0 - Exceeds expectations

**The goal** - is to calculate the average evaluation point, like 2.5
I tried to use IF condition, but it works only for 2 values, and I have 3.

Could you please advise how can I calculate in separate column on at the bottom of the column with my values the average **digit**?

Comment: The average of what, exactly? Maybe you could share a spreadsheet with us, demonstrating what you want?

Answer (score 3):

You can nest the `IF` statements, to support any number of options.

Given that cell `A1` contains one of `1.0 - Doesn't meet expectations`, `2.0 - Meets expectations` or `3.0 - Exceeds expectations`, input this formula in `B1`:

```
=IF(A1="1.0 - Doesn't meet expectations", 1, IF(A1 = "2.0 - Meets expectations", 2, 3))
```

Another option is to just extract the first three characters of the cell contents, and use that as a number:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A2, 3))
```

The number resulting from any of these formulas can the be used to calculate an average

```
=AVERAGE(B1:B2)
```

See [the example spreadsheet I set up](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RaoDT192wLUCZY0AAAc5hs61_93RRdIPYCdeeO9z9GU/edit?usp=sharing).